# make the whole section responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was trying to make a section of website, responsive by giving heights and widths in % instead of pixels, but it is not working so please help to make it responsive. 
while changing resolution it is not working, i want the ending border with it also while it goes to different resolution..
HTML

```
<section class="banner ik">
    <div class="img_box">
            <div class="fadein">
            <img src="banner/b1_03.jpg">
            <img src="banner/ban2_03.jpg">
            <img src="banner/ban3_03.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
            $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function(){
              $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                 .next('img').fadeIn()
                 .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
              3000);
        });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.banner{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        border-bottom: solid 1px black;

        margin: 0 auto;

}

.ik {
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
height: 405px;
}

.img_box{

width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}

.fadein {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 420px;
}
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: post your code in fiddle will be better?

Comment: Rather making so much complex css and html you can use Bootstrap Responsive js. It is very easy to learn and simple to apply. getbootstrap.com

Comment: Okay thanks for your response v:)